# bufferedreader Inputstream reader changes...?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
URL u = new URL(url);
String expected = "";
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
Reader r= new InputStreamReader(in);
```

so here is my code and i want a very little help that is the above is to fetch the content from url but now i want to use the same code for reading content from file what i need to change in above code....i mean there should be something which i need to change in the place of uc.getInputStream()...so what is that

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question here is. Are you asking why `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());` is correct in Java (why does it compile)? Or maybe are you interested in what is the role of `in` variable, or maybe what `uc.getInputStream()` does?

Answer (score 0):

Look at class [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

You can simply user that code and do it in similar way.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/temp/test.txt"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(out.toString());   //Prints the string content read from input stream
        reader.close();
```